# Why do I need to query android.intent.action.MAIN for IABHelper to work for target SDKs +31 on the Emulator

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

when I switched to `targetSdkVersion 33`, google's `IABHelper` would

```
throw new IllegalStateException("IAB helper is not set up. Can't perform operation: " + operation);
```

in their method

```
checkSetupDone(String operation)
```

only on the Emulator, and when I added

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

it was resolved, what does querying android.intent.action.MAIN mean? and what's its relation to the problem I'm facing?

when I call `getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)` I get this list:

```
com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.YouTubeTikTokRoot_Application
com.google.android.apps.gsa.binaries.velvet.app.VelvetRoot_Application
com.google.android.apps.messaging.platform.BuglePlatform_Application
com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication
com.android.vending.VendingApplication
com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
com.android.camera.app.CameraApp
com.android.nfc.NfcApplication
com.android.deskclock.DeskClockApplication
com.android.statementservice.StatementServiceApplication
com.google.android.apps.gmail.application.tiktok.Hub_Application
com.android.permissioncontroller.PermissionControllerApplication
com.google.android.setupwizard.SetupWizardApplication
com.farsitel.bazaar.BazaarApp
com.android.se.SEApplication
com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.Wellbeing_Application
com.google.android.apps.docs.drive.DriveApplication
com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.app.OemGoogleMapsApplication
org.chromium.chrome.browser.base.SplitChromeApplication
com.android.dialer.binary.aosp.AospDialerApplication
com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerApplication
co.g.App
com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.GoogleTTSRoot_Application
com.google.android.apps.photos.PhotosApplication
com.google.android.calendar.CalendarApplication
com.android.managedprovisioning.ManagedProvisioningApplication
com.android.documentsui.DocumentsApplication
com.android.server.NetworkPermissionConfig
com.google.android.settings.intelligence.IntelligenceApplication
com.google.android.apps.auto.components.app.stubapp.GhStubApplication
com.google.android.apps.wallpaper.picker.WallpapersApplication
com.android.phone.PhoneApp
com.android.systemui.SystemUIApplication
com.google.android.apps.youtube.music.application.YouTubeMusicTikTokRoot_Application
com.google.pixel.exo.core.ExoApplication
com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiverApp
com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterApp
com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.latin.ImeLatinApp
com.google.android.apps.restore.RestoreApplication
```

and when I remove the query, the list shrinks to:

```
com.android.providers.media.MediaApplication
com.android.vending.VendingApplication
com.android.nfc.NfcApplication
com.android.statementservice.StatementServiceApplication
com.android.permissioncontroller.PermissionControllerApplication
com.android.se.SEApplication
com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.Wellbeing_Application
com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerApplication
co.g.App
com.google.android.apps.speech.tts.googletts.GoogleTTSRoot_Application
com.android.managedprovisioning.ManagedProvisioningApplication
com.android.server.NetworkPermissionConfig
com.android.phone.PhoneApp
com.android.systemui.SystemUIApplication
com.google.pixel.exo.core.ExoApplication
com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterApp
```

so to be precise this list was added:

```
com.google.android.apps.youtube.app.YouTubeTikTokRoot_Application
com.google.android.apps.gsa.binaries.velvet.app.VelvetRoot_Application
com.google.android.apps.messaging.platform.BuglePlatform_Application
com.android.contacts.ContactsApplication
com.android.camera.app.CameraApp
com.android.deskclock.DeskClockApplication
com.google.android.apps.gmail.application.tiktok.Hub_Application
com.google.android.setupwizard.SetupWizardApplication
com.farsitel.bazaar.BazaarApp
com.google.android.apps.docs.drive.DriveApplication
com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.app.OemGoogleMapsApplication
org.chromium.chrome.browser.base.SplitChromeApplication
com.android.dialer.binary.aosp.AospDialerApplication
com.google.android.apps.photos.PhotosApplication
com.google.android.calendar.CalendarApplication
com.android.documentsui.DocumentsApplication
com.google.android.settings.intelligence.IntelligenceApplication
com.google.android.apps.auto.components.app.stubapp.GhStubApplication
com.google.android.apps.wallpaper.picker.WallpapersApplication
com.google.android.apps.youtube.music.application.YouTubeMusicTikTokRoot_Application
com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver.CellBroadcastReceiverApp
com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.latin.ImeLatinApp
com.google.android.apps.restore.RestoreApplication
```